# Kendo - Grid - Aggregate with Complex Objects

Tags: grid, aggregate, kendo-ui, complextype

I have a Kendo UI grid. The grid has a datasource with complex object data. For example, {"foo": {"bar" : 10}}. Although the column field can navigate the object graph (i.e. foo.bar), the aggregate field doesn't seem to be able to.

Here's the code:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   dataSource: {
       data: [
           {"foo": {"bar": 10}},
           {"foo": {"bar": 20}}
       ],

       aggregate: [
           {field: "foo.bar", aggregate: "sum"}
       ]  
   },
   columns: [
       {
           field: "foo.bar",
           footerTemplate: "Sum: #= sum # "
      }
  ]   
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6shF/1/

Firebug reports "TypeError: data.foo is undefined" in line 8 of kendo.all.min.js.

Am I doing something incorrectly? If this is a bug in Kendo, is there a way to work around this? I have to keep the objects complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a "better" anwser from Kendo Support:

The behavior you are experiencing is caused by the fact that the "path" you have specified will be used as a key in the map created as result of the aggregation. Producing a object similar to the following:

{ "foo.bar" :  { sum: 30 } }

Unfortunately, this construct is not supported by the footer template generation and will not be resolved correctly. A possible workaround for this scenario is to use a function instead. I have modify the sample in order to illustrate this.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: [
            {"foo": {"bar": 10}},
            {"foo": {"bar": 20}}
        ],

        aggregate: [
            {field: "foo.bar", aggregate: "sum"}
        ]
    },
    columns: [
        {
            field: "foo.bar",
            footerTemplate: function(data) { return "Sum: " + data["foo.bar"].sum; }
        }
    ]   
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have complex objects in aggregates since dynamically generated function for evaluating it, thinks that `foo.bar` is the name of the field (just one field)?

Do you really need that complex field?

I might understand that the server (providing the data of the grid) sends that complex `foo` but you can always *flatten* it using `parse` or `data` functions in the datasource. Something like this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:{
        data:[
            {"foo":{"bar":10}},
            {"foo":{"bar":20}}
        ],
        aggregate:[
            {field:"foo_bar", aggregate:"sum"}
        ],
        schema:   {
            parse:function (data) {
                var res = [];
                $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
                    res.push({ "foo_bar":elem.foo.bar })
                });
                return res;
            }
        }
    },
    columns:   [
        {
            field:         "foo_bar",
            footerTemplate:"Sum: #= sum # "
        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Where I transform received `foo.bar` into `foo_bar` and use this for aggregation.

Comment: That's right. The server returns a large complex object. I can flatten only the columns needed in aggregation. It is quite a few columns though and the data set could be large, but it sounds like flattening is the only way (or perhaps using a function in the footerTemplate and building my own aggregating in that function). Thanks for your help.